# connect to gopro through USB with opengopro

Tags: python-3.x, http, webcam, gopro

The [docs](https://gopro.github.io/OpenGoPro/http_2_0#usb-2) shows how to get the socket address but how can it be used? It feels like the docs left me hanging. [The steps](https://gopro.github.io/OpenGoPro/http_2_0#usb) are to connect it via USB, then "Send HTTP command to enable wired USB control"??

I am trying to use the gopro as a webcam via USB (their app doesn't work).

Comment: Also have the same issue. The docs for USB control are virtually non-existent. Did you make any headway? I'm wanting to control via USB, start/stop recording, choose various recording presets, and show a preview while recording, hopefully in 1080p.

Answer (score 0):

The specifications from their documentation site state that Hero5 Session is not supported for this.[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g2qwt.png)